# Can a Brushless Motor Maintain a Constant Speed When the Load Changes?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I just bought a bldc motor from https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/bldc-motor.  I'm trying to figure out the simplest way of running a BLDC motor at a constant speed. I'm open to help.

Comment: What research have you done yourself?

Comment: I lost count on how many motors are on the page you linked. Please link to the data sheet (a .pdf document) for the specific motor you purchased. We use pdf data sheets in EE because we can store them as a record of what the device is that we bought. Reason: they provide many more details than a web-page and, web-page's can be changed but the stored pdf cannot be changed. Pdf's also usually give quality information about the supplier or original manufacturer.

Comment: A control system with MCU is required to keep the number of revolutions constant. However, you need to be careful about the power dissipated by the engine.

Comment: Assuming your controller and motor are rated suitably, then it's up to your control loop and the dynamics of the load as to how well the speed will be kept constant depending on the load

Answer (score 1):

> Can a Brushless Motor Maintain a Constant Speed When the Load Changes?

No, at least not perfectly. There is no feedback system that will allow the controller to instantaneously correct for an increased load. At a bare minimimum, the rotor speed will decrease while angle between the rotor and stator magnetic fields increases, even if the controller compensates for that later.

It is possible to have the motor controller maintain the same speed at different loads *eventually*. That is, if the motor were spinning at 1000 RPM with no load, and then a load was applied, it will *eventually* spin at 1000 RPM again. But it is by no means guaranteed that an arbitrary motor controller will do this. In many feedback systems, the "error signal" is never *exactly* zero (except as an exceptional case). If the error signal is a measure of the angular difference between the rotor's magnetic field and the stator's magnetic field, then it is possible for the error signal to be non-zero, while the rotational speed is equal to the commanded speed. The controller can in that case maintain a constant rotational speed *eventually*. However, if the error signal is a measure of the difference between the actual rotational speed and the commanded speed, and if the controller requires a non-zero error signal to work properly, then a load on the motor will necessarily cause the motor to slow down slightly.

Not all feedback control systems require a non-zero error signal to work properly, however! By integrating the error signal, any error, no matter how small, will cause an increasing magnitude of an internal "integral" signal. Eventually, that integral signal will become large enough to cause the controller to compensate it's output. With such a controller, even if the error signal is the difference between commanded speed and actual speed, it can eventually reach commanded speed, even with varying loads.

So, the exact answer depends upon your system, both the motor and the controller.